# Запуск windows form на версиях Windows 7-10

Tags: c#, c++, c, winforms

Задача такая: написать приложение windows form, которое будет работать желательно в windows xp, 7, 10. А как минимум в семерке и десятке. Причем работать она должна в этих версиях "из коробки". Поэтому использовать net framework 4.0 , который можно установить на все эти версии, не получится.
Пока я вижу два способа как сделать такое приложение:

1. Написать приложение на с(с++), которое в зависимости от версии windows будет из ресурсов доставать нужную нам версию windows form (net Framework 2.0 или 4.5) и запускать ее. Только c++ я не знаю от слова совсем. Так что если знаете похожую реализацию поделитесь ссылкой.
2. Использовать Net Core, но как я понял он поддерживает консольные и web приложения, но никак не windows form. Во всяком случае в visual studio 2015 при установке net Core других вариантов проекта нет.

Так что поделитесь, кто знает работающее решение.

Comment: 3. Использовать Delphi/Lazarus.

Comment: может просто .net 3.5 использовать?

Comment: @4per в десятке он не стоит по умолчанию

Comment: А просто использовать установщик, который доставит .NET Framework не подходит?

Comment: а зачем городить лишнее. Программу не надо ставить, ее только надо запускать. Причем под обычным пользователем.

Comment: А можно узнать, что за приложение? И что будет, если появится код, специфичный для конкретной версии .net фреймворка? Или у Вас не появится ?

Comment: Можно, приложение запускает RDP сессии в зависимости от контекста.
машины разные, в том числе доменные и нет, и права у пользователей разные.
специфичного кода не будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас есть вариант скомпилировать программу под .NET 2.0 и использовать только эту версию фреймворка. Чтобы такое приложение запустить в системах, на которых не установлен рантайм 2.0, но есть 4+, типа Windows 8/10, можно указать совместимый рантайм в конфигурационном файле. Пример можете посмотреть, например, [в документации winsw](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/blob/master/doc/installation.md#making-winsw-compatible-with-net-runtime-40):

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```